# UNION search in multiple tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello genius programmers can help me to figure out my error in UNION search  error in "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean".

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
            $search_key = $_GET['search'];
            $sql_search = "(SELECT lastname, firstname, 'organization_member' as type FROM org_member WHERE lastname LIKE '%" . 
                            $search_key . "%' OR firstname LIKE '%" . $search_key ."%')
                            UNION
                            (SELECT title, 'fedetated_member' as type FROM fedetated_members WHERE title LIKE '%" . 
                            $search_key . "%')";

            $query_search = mysqli_query($CONNECTION, $sql_search);
        }
    ?>

    <div class='body_wrap'>
        <div class='inner_wrap'>
            <span class='text_black_big'>SEARCH RESULT FOR: <?php echo $_GET['search']; ?></span>
                <table>
                <?php while($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($query_search)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br><?php echo $row_search['organization_member'] ?><br><br><?php echo $row_search['fedetated_member'] ?><br></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: union should be 2 queries with the same number of columns and specifically data type

Comment: `echo $sql_search` and debug the printed query or show here...

Comment: Adding on to @maSTArHiAn you will need to do the queries sepearately or you can cheat by adding a dummy field in the 2nd queries select statement eg (`(SELECT '', title, 'fedetated_member' as type FROM fedetated_members WHER...`)

or you cound concat the first & last name of the first query so that they are returned as one field. `((SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) as 'full_name', 'organization_member' as type FROM org_member)`

Comment: thank you guys for the information.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables. The following are basic rules for combining the
>   result sets of two queries by using UNION: The number and the order of
>   the columns must be the same in all queries. The data types must be
>   compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is incorrect so $query_search variable equal FALSE:

> $query_search = mysqli_query($CONNECTION, $sql_search);

Your SELECT statements must select columns same type and the column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned.
You can find out more here: [UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)